# If $f \in C([0,1])$, show $f\in C^{k}([0,1])$ iff $f$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$ and has derivative at endpoints

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The following is from question 5.9 in *Folland's Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications.*

> Let $C^{k}([0,1])$ be the space of functions on $[0,1]$ possessing
>   continuous derivatives up to order $k$ on $[0,1]$, including one-sided
>   derivatives at the endpoints.
>
> ***Claim:*** If $f \in C([0,1])$, then $f\in C^{k}([0,1])$ iff $f$ is $k$
>   times continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f^{(j)}(x)$
>   and $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f^{(j)}(x)$ exists for $j \leq k$. (The mean
>   value theorem is useful).

Here are my thoughts:

1. The forward case is trivial and does not need a detailed exposition.
2. For the reverse case, since $f$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$, all we need to show is that for all $j \leq k$ the fact that $f$ is $j$ times differentiable at the endpoints implies it is $k$ times differentiable at the endpoints.
3. It follows that if we can show it is true at one endpoint (say as $x \to 1^{-}$) then the same proof should hold for the other endpoint.
4. It seems to me that if the result holds for $k=1$ we can show by induction that it holds for all $k$.

At this point I am not quite sure how to proceed. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof for $k=1$ for the derivative at $0$ : Fix $x \in (0,1]$ .For $y \in [0,x]$ let $$g(y)=f(0)+(y/x)(f(x)-f(0))$$  and  $$h(y)= f(y)-g(y).$$ Now $h(y)$ is continuous for $y \in[0,x]$ so there exists $z_1 \in (0,x)$ with $$\max \{|h(y)| : y \in [0,x]\}=|h(z_1)|,$$ and since $h(0)=h(x)=0$,  there exist  $z_2 \in (0,z_1)$ and $z_3 \in (z_1,x)$ with $$h(z_2)=h(z_3).$$which from the definitions of $h$ and $g$,  is equivalent to $$f(z_3)-f(z_2)=(z_3-z_2)\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}. $$ So we have $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}= \frac {f(z_3)-f(z_2)} {z_3-z_2} =f'(z_4)$$ for some $z_4 \in (z_2,z_3)$. Since $z_4 \in (0,x)$ we have  $$\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x} \in \{f'(z) :z \in (0,x)\}$$ and since  $\lim_{z \to 0} f'(z)$ exists,we have $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}  =\lim_{z \to 0} f'(z).$$ That is ,  $f'(0)$ exists and $f'$ is continuous at $ 0$.

Comment: Does $\frac{f(x) -f(0)}{x} \in \{f'(z): z \in (0,x)\}$ not follow directly from the mean value theorem? In particular, $f$ is continuous on $[0,x]$ and has a first derivative $(0,x)$ (since $k=1$), so by the mean value theorem there exists $z\in (0,x)$ such that $\frac{f(x) -f(0)}{x} = f'(z)$. Right?

Comment: Right .I was just being very cautious.And in my answer you can skip the steps with $z_2$ and $z_3$ and put $z_4=z_1$.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!